# Simple bar graph challenge using arrays

Tags: arrays, ruby

I am trying to solve the following challenge, which is to create a bar graph program:

"Write a program that draws bar graphs. It should:
 1. Ask the user for a list of numbers. The user enters them separated by commas, e.g. 10,4,2,7,5,1.
 2. Print a horizontal bar graph of the numbers in order. 
 3. Bars should be made up of '-'

For example

```
10,4,2,7
----------
----
--
-------
```

Note: you can assume the user will only enter integers separated by commas with no spaces."

This is a challenge that comes as part of a tutorial on Arrays, so I think that the aim is to use an array.

My thinking is to convert the user's input into an array, iterate over each number and print the corresponding number of dashes for each number. I can't work out how to do this however. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55140475/edit) so as to include your code as text instead of an image.

Comment: Your thinking seems right regarding this challenge. Do you already have a piece of code that is not working? Please paste it so that we have something to work on

Comment: Write the question here. Do not expect the reader to follow the link for you.

Comment: If it's a tutorial with a challenge, then usually everything you need to know to solve it is in the previous chapters. Try re-reading those, it should help.

Comment: Thanks guys - sorry first ever post on Stack Overflow ever so tried to post the question in the neatest  way but have edited it to remove the image :)

Comment: Do not put your code in a comment.  If you read the help section for the site, you'll see that it is a requirement to put your code in the question itself.  Please edit the question and delete the comment containing the code.

Answer (score 2):

Since this a challenge, I will not give you the answer explicitly but rather some clues which will help you in solving the challenge.

To start with, your program accepts a *comma separated value* string:

```
10,4,2,7,5,1
```

This can be converted into an array of elements by using the `String#split` method and then converting each element to an integer by calling `String#to_i` on each element.

```
array = '10,4,2,7,5,1'.split(',')
array.map! { |item| item.to_i }
```

The above two steps will give you an *array of numbers*.

Calling `each` on the array will let you *iterate* through the array passing a num to a block given to the `each` method:

```
array.each do |num|
  # print_dashes(num)
end
```

Printing dashes is easy. There are two simple methods available to print objects to your terminal: `print` and `puts`
Every call to `print x` will print `x` *on the same line*
Every call to `puts x` will print `x` *on a new line*

A string can be multiplied to extend itself. For example:

```
dashes = '-' * 10
print(dashes)
```

Comment: `String#*` is cool and all, but calling `print` in a loop would be more within means of a complete beginner.

Comment: Thank you so much ashmaroli, that has really helped! :)

Comment: There's more than one way to do things in Ruby. The joy lies in learning the game and then the tricks.

Answer (score -1):

```
gets.split(","){|x| puts "-" * Integer(x, exception: false)}
```

Comment: With no explanation?  That's a lot for a beginner to unpack.